# How to use a 24v 3A drill motor from a PSU 12V 20A?

Tags: motor, dc-dc-converter, boost

How to use a 24V 3A drill motor from a PSU 12V 20A?
I'm using a motor that at 24V has 28000rpm, and at 12V only 10000rpm. Is there any step-up that I can use or make to use the PSU as input?

Comment: Lots of laptops use 19VDC at 3A; a used power adapter should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, pay 50 dollars, and you have a good 120 Watt converter that makes 24V from 12V. They are often ment to be used in cars. For that money, you can also buy a power supply of 24V.